# How can I get wordpress post pages to including post id in the permalink on customized wordpress theme?

Tags: php, wordpress

I had a previous coder move my site from a custom cms to a custom wordpress theme.

Posts are shown correctly when there is no post-id in the permalink. However, I would like to include the postid on the site posts. My permalinks now look like www.website.com/post-title/ although I would like them to be www.website.com/123/post-title/. I believe all my issues are coming down to one function.

http://pastie.org/10498435

The code on that page does various things based on vars found in the url. I am not 100% sure if this is the only problem, but it is the only one I can find. I have a custom post type created on my site that seems to work fine. The permalinks seem to fully work. When visiting a post page with the postid in the url (changing it via the permalink settings) I get a 404 page. I also get a 404 page when I try and view the author page. I have no clue where to even begin to figure out what the problem is with the author page.

Site: http://www.frontdesktip.com/blog/

Comment: Unless I'm misunderstanding something...why not just [edit the Permalink settings in the Admin](https://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks#Choosing_your_permalink_structure) to `/%post_id%/%postname%/`?

Comment: When we do this, we get a 404 page. I believe it's from some of the customization of the previous coder.

Comment: When does that function get called? It's probably a parameter in a add_action function. Also, do category pages work? On first glance, it seems to be an overly aggressive rewrite rule.

Comment: That's pretty much what I thought, but I cant find any rewrite rules that would do this. The htaccess file just has the default Wordpress code, and I haven't found any other functions that mess with posts and pages in this way.

The above function is called using add_action( "parse_request", array($this, "fdt_parse_request") );